# Creating dynamic div with filled dropdowns in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need to create a page where contents of page are created dynamically.
That is all text boxes and dropdowns are dynamically created based on rights and finally attaching to a div

```
public void BindPageData()
{
    try
    {
        string OutMsg = string.Empty;            
        OutMsg = GetPageCommentsHTML();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(OutMsg))
            div_dynamic.InnerHtml = OutMsg;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      Log.Errlog("Error in BindPageData Method" + ex.Message); }
    }
}
```

value of string OutMsg

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding='0' border="0px" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldtxt" align="right">
            NAME:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddr1" runat="server" CssClass="fieldtxtbox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommand_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>                                           
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldtxt" align="right" Visible="false">
            CLASS
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="fieldtxtbox1"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommand2_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>                                      
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldtxt" align="right">
            SUBJECT
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="fieldtxtbox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommand3_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>                                       
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I am able to display all fields like text boxes and labels. What my requirement is that need to fill dropdown list while binding data to the dynamic div.
How can I do that?

Comment: How is string OutMsg generated?

Comment: @agileMike : from the stored procedure (by calling GetPageCommentsHTML(); method there calls the stored procedure)

Comment: The OutMsg is generated from a sql proc, but it's not true html - if you send that to a browser it is not going to know what an asp tag should do. If you want to have the proc generate the html then it needs to be straight html, not asp web forms markup. Following that approach, you'd need to build the html for a select element and it's options in the proc.